# radiobutton is not selected while select radiobutton in listview

Tags: android, listview, radio-group

I created custom listview with two radiobutton in radiogroup.

My code getter and setter file

**Item_radio.java**

```
package com.example.customlistview_radio;

public class Item_radio 
{
    public boolean isSelected_radio1;
    public boolean isSelected_radio2;

    public Item_radio(boolean radio1_status,boolean radio2_status)
    {
        this.isSelected_radio1=radio1_status;
        this.isSelected_radio2=radio2_status;
    }

    public boolean isSelected_radio1() {
        return isSelected_radio1;
    }
    public void setSelected_radio1(boolean isSelected_radio1) {
        this.isSelected_radio1 = isSelected_radio1;
    }
    public boolean isSelected_radio2() {
        return isSelected_radio2;
    }
    public void setSelected_radio2(boolean isSelected_radio2) {
        this.isSelected_radio2 = isSelected_radio2;
    }
}
```

**MyRadioAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.customlistview_radio;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class MyRadioAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    Context context;
    List<Item_radio> radioList;
    public MyRadioAdapter(Context context,List<Item_radio> radiolist)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.radioList=new ArrayList<Item_radio>();
        this.radioList.addAll(radiolist);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return radioList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return radioList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        RadioButton radio_button1;
        RadioButton radio_button2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if(view==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.radio_button1=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.my_radio_but1);
            holder.radio_button2=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.my_radio_but2);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (position % 2 == 1) 
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        else
        {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        final Item_radio radio = (Item_radio) getItem(position);
        holder.radio_button1.setChecked(radio.isSelected_radio1());
        holder.radio_button2.setChecked(radio.isSelected_radio2());

        holder.radio_button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                Log.e("button1","Clicked:button1");
                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)v;
                radio.setSelected_radio1(rb.isChecked());
                Log.e("button1","Clicked:button1:"+rb.isChecked());
            }
        });
        holder.radio_button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {       
                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)v;
                Log.e("button2","Clicked:button2"+rb.isChecked());
                radio.setSelected_radio2(rb.isChecked());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.customlistview_radio;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{

    ListView mylist;
    Button submit_but;

    ArrayList<Item_radio> radio_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mylist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist_demo);
        submit_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit_but);


        radio_list=new ArrayList<Item_radio>();

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            radio_list.add(new Item_radio(false,false));
        }

        mylist.setAdapter(new MyRadioAdapter(MainActivity.this, radio_list));   
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/my_radio_group"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/my_radio_but1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="radio1" />

         <RadioButton
             android:id="@+id/my_radio_but2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="radio2" />
     </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.customlistview_radio.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist_demo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >
    </ListView>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submit_but"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="submit"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

While selecting the radiobutton in list row some radiobutton is selected.

If i scroll the listview and select the radio button between last 5 or 6 items it will not selected.

Problem

**That is suppose radio button1 is not selected then i choose radiobutton2 it gets selected afterwards radiobutton1 is selected.**

My logCat

```
03-04 10:22:17.221: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:20.201: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:21.221: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:22.101: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:23.711: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:24.671: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:25.711: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:40.770: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2true
03-04 10:22:42.371: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2false
03-04 10:22:52.271: E/button2(4665): Clicked:button2false
```

Please see my locat the first 8 rows working properly.
When i click radiobutton2 in 9 th row is not getting selected print checked status false but i select the button and also the checked appearance is not changed still in unselected mode.

Am i doing anything wrong?
Please help me to solve the problem.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One works sometime and same doesn't after, It's all because of you have used `setChecked` before rest of the codes. so what I can suggest to you is just remove these lines

```
  holder.radio_button1.setChecked(radio.isSelected_radio1());
  holder.radio_button2.setChecked(radio.isSelected_radio2());
```

**UPDATE : If this harms your list, then do the following**

Just reverse your logic here, After setting the radio_1 checked, set the radio_2 unchecked. Your code looks like this

```
   holder.radio_button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("button1", "Clicked:button1");
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;

            radio.setSelected_radio1(rb.isChecked());
            radio.setSelected_radio2(!rb.isSelected());
            Log.e("button1", "Clicked:button1:" + rb.isChecked());
        }
    });
    holder.radio_button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)v;
            Log.e("button2","Clicked:button2"+rb.isChecked());
            radio.setSelected_radio2(rb.isChecked());
            radio.setSelected_radio1(!rb.isSelected());
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

Whatever currently happening is all because of your view is recycled, The final option you can use is, Remove this `if(view==null)` condition and matching `else` clause with it's code as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shree Krishna. I try your suggestion. If i do like that when i scroll the listview  the radiobuttons in listview automatically gets selected.

Comment: @Asha I updated my answer, Have a look. Leave comment if any error raised with this too. I am currently in leave for tomorrow. I will catch this after one day. Sorry for that.. But I think the final option will solve your issue, your code is fine at all.

Comment: Thanks @Shree Krishna At finally the radiobutton in all rows getting selected when **i remove the if and else condition**. But now i faced scrolling issue. i will try to fix that scrolling issue. Thanks...

Comment: Thats my pleasure... And its not scrolling issue... Its because of high CPU consumption... Its normal because your task is also heavier... So i suggest you to reduce the list items as possible, rather than trying to fix...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code little bit.

Step 1:

Create HashMap in your adapter like this

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> selectedItems  = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Step 2:
And inside of getView add the following

```
if ( selectedItems.get( position ) != null ) {
                 holder.radio_button1.setChecked(radio.isSelected_radio1()); selectedItems.get( position ) );
             }
```

Step 3:
Inside of your radio button onlick add the following

```
selectedItems.put( position, your_value);
```

Note:

Here your_value is 0 or 1. If 1 means radio button selected 0 means not seleced.

Try this let me know if you face any issues.

I am adding this only for radio button 1. First try with this. If it is working then modify your radio button 2

Edit 1:

Why don't you try with Radiogroup like the following?????

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);



            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still the problem is occurred. Understand my problem the radiobutton is not getting selected while i select either radiobutton1 or radiobutton2

Comment: The real problem is whenever you scroll  your list view getting recycled. That is the reason for the issue. So you need to save the each row selected value. I hope you understand

Comment: I understood that the view getting recycled is main problem. As per your suggestion if i want to save the selected row value, the radiobutton is selected first. My problem is here the button not getting selected while i check the radiobutton.

Comment: Thanks for your answer@Amsheer i tried your edit answer. Still problem is exist. I edit my question with logcat please see my edit...